# Не работает remove на iPhone Safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider-pagination ul li").on( "click", "a", function (e) {
        var click = $(this);
        var new_data = click.closest('section').prev()
        new_data.find('ul').remove(); 
    }); 
});
```

По нажатию на элемент пагинации идет поиск родительского тега `section` (с контентом) и удаляется все его содержимое. Код работает на всех устройствах, кроме iPhone. Что можно заменить, чтобы код работал и на айфонах?

Comment: можете показать разметку для тега _а_ по которому кликаете?

Comment: вы уверены, что проблема именно в _remove_? вообще в обработчик клика заходите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил сам. Все-таки причина была действительно в обработчике события клика, on('click') нужно было заменить на событие click и тогда все работает отлично. Первое событие иногда срабатывало, иногда нет.

Comment: можете привести код, что и на что вы поменяли?